# pdptw for optimization

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

I have to solve a Pickup Delivery Route Optimization Problem where a Single Vehicle Starts from the Depot
and reaches to first pickup point and delivers to Delivery Location within a time frame and then starts for another Pickup location.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you show any code you tried already? Your question looks very broad and lacking detail that would be needed to answer it meaningfully. Could you refine the aswer to ask for answers for specific programming problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this set of [examples](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/doc/PDP.md)

and this [guide](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing).

Comment: This is a PDPTW problem and I am not sure if Google OR has a python implementation for this.

Comment: It does. See https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw

Comment: The link you shared have only time windows for the location but doesn't have pickup delivery data like which location to pickup and which location to deliver

Comment: you can compose, these are simple examples.